# Build is disappearing from itunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

When I upload a build from xcode I'm able to see the build is processing on itunesconnect.apple.com, the image below is the screen I initially see:

[build processing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ex34AoBWoMByvHG-NRLf6iquUYFsNbZQ/view?usp=sharing)

But after I refresh the page the build disappears and doesn't reappear. It's been over an hour and I still don't see the build anymore. I've tried rearchiving but I get the same result--I see it initially but then it disappears. This is the "empty" screen I see after my build has disappeared:

[empty build](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J4rpNV7rOtTXvxnRk21VyGGpk9ZghqIO/view?usp=sharing)

Should I keep on waiting, contact support, or is this normal?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are missing some key in the plist.
Please check your email for the developer account.

App Store review may send you a email for the above issue.

Make sure you have the key 
" NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription " also added in your plist

Comment: Yes they send you an email with errors instead of simply listing them in the portal which they specially built to manage app submissions. Apple are such a PITA

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues in the past when I tab to different applications during the build upload process.  In those cases XCode seems to mess up and builds can take an exceptionally long time to process (3+ hours in my case).  In my case I just incremented the build number and generated a new version making sure to keep Xcode in focus during the upload.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the build might take around 3 hours to get processed and appear in App store depending on the size of your app. But so far I have not seen a scenario where even processing of build is not shown. I would suggest you to logout and login and then check for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got a email from apple.
[image: the screen shot as below]

I am not using camera and photo in my app, but still i got this email from apple developer team to add in my info.plist file. I don't know why to add it, but it worked.

Comment: You’re likely still requesting permission, even though you might not be using the features. Try checking the permissions in your apps .plist file in Xcode. Also look in the config.xml file.